# Disabling plugin but wpenqueue is not available

Tags: plugins, widgets, mobile

I'm trying to disable a few plugins when my mobile theme is loaded. I read somewhere about using this particular function in my mobile theme functions.php file to remove scripts and css.

```
//Disable plugins
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'smp_common','smp_cookie','smp_colorbox','smp_meerkat','jquery','query-ui-sortable' );
}
//Deregister styles
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

Going by the above, i've been able to remove a few scripts, but unable to remove the 'share post' plugin as wp_enqueue is not mentioned in the script. Is there an alternative to disable this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to fix the plugin code. Also, send a bug report to the plugin author. I'm sure she wants to improve the plugin.

Comment: This is not correct. IF the plugin is setup with proper script / style enqueues, they can absolutely be removed. @Chris_O below is correct.

Comment: @Pippin Re-read the question: _as wp_enqueue is not mentioned in the script_. The missing _proper setup_ is the whole point of my answer …

Comment: bah, my bad. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

[`wp_deregister_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) only takes a single script handle as the argument.  Also it should be hooked into wp_enqueue_scripts not wp_print_scripts.

Also if the plugin is not using wp_enqueue it must be hooking into wp_head with add_action to print the inline script calls.  You can remove the add_action function in the plugin with remove_action.